# How to Remove Mate Grub loader and change to default ubuntu loader?

Tags: boot, 18.04, grub2, bootloader, ubuntu-mate

I installed Mate-Desktop on my ubuntu 18.04 and i removed it but the Grub loader is not removed/changed it still boots with the Mate logo, i need the default Ubuntu loader how to bring it back

O/P of `update-alternatives --config default.plymouth`:

```
There are 3 choices for the alternative default.plymouth (providing /usr/share/plymouth/themes/default.plymouth).

  Selection    Path                                                                           Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/share/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-mate-logo/ubuntu-mate-logo.plymouth           150       auto mode
  1            /usr/share/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo.plymouth                     100       manual mode
  2            /usr/share/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-mate-logo/ubuntu-mate-logo-scale-2.plymouth   149       manual mode
  3            /usr/share/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-mate-logo/ubuntu-mate-logo.plymouth           150       manual mode
```

Comment: what is the output of `update-alternatives --config default.plymouth`

Comment: Edited in orginal post @PRATAP & changing it to 1 will thisis solve this probelm ?

Comment: ok.. run the same command with `sudo` select 1 enter.. and run below command..

Comment: Thanks Man @PRATAP

Comment: `sudo update-initramfs -u` and reboot..

Comment: Thank you @UnKNOWn, I found that last one did the trick